# Buscar valores repetidos en array multidimensional (PHP)

Tags: php, array

Como puedo sacar los valores repetidos dentro de un array multidimensional en PHP? He encontrado algunas funciones pero no me han funcionado. Hay alguna función nativa que haga eso?

```
<?php
$array = array(array(7,18), array(12,7), array(12, 7, 13));
$result = array();


$first = $array[0];
for($i=1; $i<count($array); $i++){
 $result = array_intersect ($first, $array[$i]);
 $first = $result;
}
print_r($result);//7
?>
```

---

```
function array_icount_values($arr,$lower=true) { 
     $arr2=array(); 
     if(!is_array($arr['0'])){$arr=array($arr);} 
     foreach($arr as $k=> $v){ 
      foreach($v as $v2){ 
      if($lower==true) {$v2=strtolower($v2);} 
      if(!isset($arr2[$v2])){ 
          $arr2[$v2]=1; 
      }else{ 
           $arr2[$v2]++; 
           } 
    } 
    } 
    return $arr2; 
} 

$arr = array_icount_values($arry);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
exit;
```

He encontrado esto en Stackoverflow pero no me funciona ni una ni otra.

Comment: "*sacar los valores repetidos*" <-- por "*sacar*" querés decir "obtener" o "eliminar"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tienes php5.6:

```
<?php
// Array multidimensional
$a = [
  [1,2,3,4,5,6, 33], 
  [1,2,5,6,7,9], 
  [3,4,1,2,8,5, 
    [1,2,3,9, 
      [8, 
        [34]
      ]
    ] , 
    33, 34
  ]
];

// Primero hacemos la matriz de una sola dimensión
$b = [];
array_walk_recursive($a, function($a) use (&$b) {
  $b[] = $a;
});

/* En caso de ser un array de 2 dimensiones podemos usar
$b = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $a);
ó
$b = array_merge(...$a); <-- en el caso de utilizar PHP > 5.6

*/ 

// array_count_values: cuenta cada valor retornando un array (valor => cantidad)
// luego filtramos los que tengan un valor > 1
// luego recuperamos las keys (que son los valores originales
$repetidos = array_keys(
               array_filter(
                 array_count_values($b), function($v, $k) {
                   return $v > 1;
               }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH)
             ); // es necesario PHP 5.6 para utilizar tanto keys como values en array_filter

var_dump($repetidos);

// OUTPUT:
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(4)
  [4]=>
  int(5)
  [5]=>
  int(6)
}
```

Comment: Esta es! Funciona perfectamente! Muchas gracias!

Comment: Serías tan amable de explicar la diferencia entre esta respuesta y mi propuesta para no haberla marcado como válida? Sólo por curiosidad :/

Comment: @CésarGonzález al parecer es por que modificas el valor de la variable...

Comment: No se modifica ningún valor de la variable de entrada. En fin...

Comment: tiene razón @CésarGonzález, leí mal tu código. No sé por que ruralGalaxy indica que no es correcto, pero es básicamente el mismo enfoque que apliqué, solo que utilicé array_filter. De todas formas, encuentro más concisa la línea 1, ya que aplica de mejor forma un flatten del array. Actualizaré mi respuesta con tu línea, si no es molestia

Comment: Sin ningún problema @PabloAlcantar. Cuando leí tu aproximación al problema me llamó la atención que era muy similar a la mía, por eso pregunté en inicio. Pensaba que tenía alguna errata.

Comment: La actualización que has hecho no me funciona al ser lo mismo que ha puesto @CésarGonzález,, por lo que me quedo con la primera versión que si me funciona. La parte de call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array); no me funciona, por eso no la había dado por buena. De hecho la actualización de Pablo no me funciona, por lo que como respuesta buena daría la primera versión. Pero imagino que ambas son correctas y os doy las gracias por vuestras respuestas.

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar por qué no te funciona? El resultado de ambas soluciones es exactamente el mismo

Comment: he corrido ambas versiones y me han funcionado sin problema. Inclusive, utilizando argument unpacking (solo > php5.6), funciona igual: `$b = array_merge(...$a);`

Comment: @PabloAlcantar - Quizás deberías aclarar que funciona para 2 dimensiones y no más. Es decir, no aplica a *cualquier* array *multidimensional*.

Comment: @Mariano Corregí el codigo para que funcione para un array N dimensional, gracias!

Comment: @CésarGonzález finalmente comprendí la problemática: el array es N-dimensional, por lo que la solución tipo con `call_user_func_array` o `array_merge(...$a)` no funcionan en todos los casos. Debido al ejemplo puesto por rural, pensamos que funcionaba en todos los casos, cuando en realidad, no.

Comment: @RuralGalaxy a modo de recomendación, cuando una solución propuesta no te funcione, trata de ejemplificar los casos en los que falla, para así saber que ocurre. En este caso, a pesar de haber dicho multidimensional, la mayoría asumimos que tu array no tendría mas de 2 dimensiones debido al ejemplo que pusiste.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar esta combinación siempre y cuando el array no tenga más niveles sin necesidad de bucles:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge',$array);
$result = array_count_values ($result);
$result = array_diff($result,array(1));
$result = array_keys($result);
```

la función `array_merge` une los elementos del array en un único array.

`array_count_values` nos devuelve el número de repeticiones de cada valor dentro del array.

Con `array_diff($array,array(1))` encontramos la diferencia entre nuestro array de repeticiones y un array con un único elemento con valor 1. En esencia eliminamos las keys con valor 1.

Para terminar, obtenemos las keys con `array_keys`.

Escrito en una única línea:

```
$result = array_keys(array_diff(array_count_values (call_user_func_array('array_merge',$array)),array(1)));
```

Comment: En caso de querer mirar los valores repetidos dentro de ese array? Es decir no quiero ningún filtro de búsqueda, solo que me saque los repetidos.

Comment: Con array_diff($result,array(1)) estás eliminando los elementos con una única aparición, por lo tanto sólo quedarán los elementos que están repetidos.

Comment: Esta forma es mucho más directa que la respuesta aceptada... Quizás la clave está en solucionarlo para *cualquier* array *multidimensional*, que hasta ahora no fue resuelto por ninguna respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la funcion de php `in_array()`

Funciona de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Existe Irix";
}
if (in_array("mac", $os)) {
    echo "Existe mac";
}
?>
```

Lo que hace es comprobar si un valor esta dentro de un array.

Te dejo un enlace a la documentación: http://php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php

Comment: Multidimensional

Comment: Para ello tendrias que hacer lo mismo, solo que tendria que estar dentro de un `for` @RuralGalaxy

Comment: @AlbertoMier ¿y cómo sería la solución usando `in_array()`?